# Optimal grid size for kernel-density estimation

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing

I am generating 2D kernel density distributions for every pair of numeric columns in a data set, using `kde2d` function in the `MASS` package in R.

This takes the following parameters:

```
kde2d(x, y, h, n=25, lims = c(range(x), range(y)))
```

where `n` is the "Number of grid points in each direction. Can be scalar or a length-2 integer vector".

I want to optimize the dimensions of the grid for every pair of columns. At the moment, I used a fixed dimensions of 10x10. Does anyone know a formula for optimizing the grid size so I can generate optimal density estimations for each pair of columns?

Thanks

Comment: please edit your question to fix the spelling of the keyword "kernel" in both the title and body

Comment: Why you want to use pairwise 2D kernels rather then single multivariate kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described by Venables and Ripley (2002), grid is about the number of points that kernel density is estimated on:

> We apply two-dimensional kernel analysis directly; this is most
>   straightforward for the normal kernel aligned with axes, that is, with
>   variance $\operatorname{diag}(h^2_x;h^2_y)$. Then the kernel estimate
>   is
>
> $$ f(x, y) = \frac{\sum_s \phi((x-x_s)/h_x) \phi((y-y_s)/h_y)}{nh_x
>  h_y} $$
>
> which can be evaluated on a grid as $XY^T$ where $X_{is} =
>  \phi((gx_i-x_s)/h_x)$ and ($gx_i$) are the grid points, and similarly
>   for $Y$.

So there is nothing to optimize in here -- simply if you take more points, you'd get more precise estimates. More gridpoints means also that your computation might get slower.

---

Venables, W. N. and Ripley, B. D. (2002) *Modern Applied Statistics with S.* Fourth edition. Springer.